# GluonFX on android: Push notification are not working when the app is closed

Tags: android, javafx, gluon, javafxports, gluonfx

I integrated the push notification service from "attach" according to the documentation. and the push notification sending is handled via Firebase and Spring-boot for sending the notification.

The push notification is working fine while the application is running. either in the foreground or in the background.

But when the app is closed (or killed) the android system shows an error message "[appName] has stopped" and i have an exception in the logs like this one

```
[SUB] [91mE/AndroidRuntime(13611): FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle[0m
[SUB] [91mE/AndroidRuntime(13611): Process: XXX.XXXX.XXXXXXX, PID: 13611[0m
[SUB] [91mE/AndroidRuntime(13611): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process XXX.XXXX.XXXXXXX. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.[0m
[SUB] [91mE/AndroidRuntime(13611):  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:184)[0m
[SUB] [91mE/AndroidRuntime(13611):  at com.google.firebase.messaging.MessagingAnalytics.logToScion(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:99)[0m
[SUB] [91mE/AndroidRuntime(13611):  at com.google.firebase.messaging.MessagingAnalytics.logNotificationReceived(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:2)[0m
[SUB] [91mE/AndroidRuntime(13611):  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.passMessageIntentToSdk(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:34)[0m
[SUB] [91mE/AndroidRuntime(13611):  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleMessageIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:27)[0m
[SUB] [91mE/AndroidRuntime(13611):  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:17)[0m
[SUB] [91mE/AndroidRuntime(13611):  at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService.lambda$processIntent$0$EnhancedIntentService(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:43)[0m
[SUB] [91mE/AndroidRuntime(13611):  at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source:6)[0m
[SUB] [91mE/AndroidRuntime(13611):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)[0m
[SUB] [91mE/AndroidRuntime(13611):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)[0m
[SUB] [91mE/AndroidRuntime(13611):  at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:6)[0m
[SUB] [91mE/AndroidRuntime(13611):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I added the required lines in the AndroidManifset.xml according to the documentation, like that

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'
    package='XXX.XXX.XXXXXX' android:versionCode='X'
    android:versionName='X.X'>
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application android:label='XXXXXX'
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name='com.gluonhq.helloandroid.MainActivity'
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name='android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' />
                <action android:name='android.intent.action.MAIN' />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.gluonhq.helloandroid.PushFcmMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.gluonhq.helloandroid.PushNotificationJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.gluonhq.helloandroid.PushNotificationActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.gluonhq.helloandroid.MainActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.gluonhq.helloandroid.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Do I miss something here ??
I checked the docs from docs.gluonhq.com and the samples and attach's docs, and also charm lib docs but i did not find something i still missing to keep it working !!

I tried to integrate the push notification in JavaFX mobile application according to GluonFX docs and it works but not in all cases

Comment: Please do not take this personally, but I would recommend you to get lost of Gluon for mobile and just learn Android development with Java or Kotlin. Trust me, you will never get happy with Gluon for mobile. Too much to explain about android and "compatibility between versions" - Just trust me.

Comment: Actually i found it complex to implement even small things, but I was always thinking because the learning curvy is high and I just in the beginning.

Comment: Yes, that's the thing my friend. Download Android Studio and you will have everything in better: A perfect "SceneBuilder", a perfect IDE for Android dev, an in built Emulator for a device, and more. Everything working out of the box! You will get your app running in no time! Do it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Problem,
I downloaded Attach Code, and after a while of trying, I built it successfully locally.

Upgrading the Android service and firebase libs was enough to solve the problem

```
implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.4.1'
```